# ADF change columns of data type in Sink using copy data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

Does anyone have experienced on transforming data type of columns when copying from source and sink with the specific data type in adf.

From Microsoft documentation, i noticed that the adf copy data can perform
1. Convert from native source types to Azure Data Factory interim data types
2. Convert from Azure Data Factory interim data types to native sink type

Currently, I want to copy data from a hive table which store all the column as String, so when using adf to copy data and landed it as parquet with correct data type, in which some column could be int, datetime, string and so on. Therefore, I have using dynamic mapping when copying data by creating dynamic json code.

```
"translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "mappings": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "commentid",
                    "type": "Int32"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "commentid",
                    "type": "Int32"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "comment",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "comment",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "commenteduser",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "commenteduser",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "name": "commenteddatetime",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "commenteddatetime",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

However, as a result, the copying process is successful without any error message. But when I have create table on top of these parquet file, the data type of these columns are still showing all as String.

Does anyone here have faced this issues before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON which you have posted I do not see any transformation in the data types . I am not sure if you just shared the columns which had the default mapping . You can try the expicit mapping and i think it should work